# A clickonce deployed application is installed only for the specific user?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, windows-xp, clickonce

Are there any defaults in the clickonce installation?

If someone decides to install the application, this application will be availiable to all the users of the computer?

I guess the answer is no. They can only use the application if they log into the user account who installed it... but sometimes it is better to ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, according to this matrix in the Microsoft article "C[hoosing Between ClickOnce and Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973805.aspx)"

"Install for All Users" is not supported. As said in the article (emphasis mine):

> Now that I've taken a quick look at features of both Windows Installer and ClickOnce, you will note that **each technology was quite different goals**.

Answer (score 1):

ClickOnce applications are deployed into a folder nested deep within the user's profile folder (under C:\Users on Vista/7 - you can find it in the %USERPROFILE% environment variable), so they're only accessible by the user who installs them.

There's nothing stopping each user on the PC from installing their own copy of the application, though, and ClickOnce apps generally have a small footprint, so this is a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

See this page at microsoft.com, it has a table with differences between windows installer and Clickonce:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973805.aspx